# how to select rows from one data frame based in other data frame R (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames: `df1` and `df2`

```
ID <- c('PD1', 'PD1', 'PD2', 'PD2')
run <- c('A1', 'A4', 'A6', 'A7')
df <- data.frame(ID=ID, run =run)

name <- c('n1', 'n1', 'n1','n1', 'n1', 'n1')
run <- c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6')
value <- c(4.5, 6.7, 0.9, 8.2, 5.7, 9.4)
df2 <- data.frame(name =name, run=run, value = value)
```

and I would like to subset my df2 based on the values in df1 to obtain this result

```
name run  value
n1  A1   4.5
n1  A4   8.2
n1  A6   9.4
```

I've tried this

```
NewDataframe <- merge(df2, df1 , by= 'run',all.x=FALSE)
```

which works but I only one to keep the cols in `df2`

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  filter(run %in% df$run)
```

Result

```r
  name run value
1   n1  A1   4.5
2   n1  A4   8.2
3   n1  A6   9.4
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` you can subset like this:

```
df2[which(df2$run %in% df$run),]
  name run value
1   n1  A1   4.5
4   n1  A4   8.2
6   n1  A6   9.4
```

In `dplyr` you could use `left_join`:

```
left_join(df, df2, by = "run") %>% na.omit(.)
```

Comment: so what is the main different between left_join and filter as both results are the same?

Comment: the former joins two dataframes the latter filters one dataframe